# Is this a correct implementation of aligned_malloc()

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, alignment, allocation

To immprove performance i was trying to implement a aligned_malloc() function to allocate new memory with an aligned address , i know the "new" operator returns always an aligned address but i want to write my own function for better understanding , this is my try :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
in purpose let's make our struct not aligned
*/
struct s{
        char foo[3]; 
};
s * array = NULL;
template <class t>
t* aligned_malloc(size_t array_size)
{
    t* array = NULL;
    char * ptr = (char*)  malloc((array_size+1)*sizeof(t)); // array_size+1 to not get out of memory when incrementing pointer
    while((((uintptr_t)ptr)%sizeof(t)) != 0 )
    ++ptr;
    return ((t*)ptr); 
}
int main()
{
    struct s * array = aligned_malloc<s>(10);
    /*
    let's test for crashs 
    */
    for (int c=0;c<10;c++)
    {
        array[c].foo[3] = 'f';
     }
    std::cout<<(((int)array)%sizeof(s))<<std::endl; // allways show '0' ,like the operator "new"
    system("pause");

}
```

An other way to do it , is by creating a memory manager that allocates a big memory block and returns the aligned address for each request .

**Note** : im not assuming that this is the correct way to do it , i wrote this for learning purposes , not assuming & not claiming .

Comment: What's the alignment restriction?  Assuming you're trying to duplicate other implementations of `aligned_malloc()`, you'd have to allow the caller to specify the actual alignment restriction (8 bytes, 16 bytes, 1 megabyte...).  Also, you should probably use `size_t` instead of `int` as the type of your parameters.  `size_t` is unsigned, and will be large enough to handle all possible memory requests.  `int` is signed - and requests for amounts of memory less than zero don't make sense.  `int` also tends to be 32 bits, which limits memory requests to less than 2 GB.

Comment: it will be nice if you write an answer in wich you edit my code

Comment: alignment should be calculated according to architecture's native value but not size of struct, think about having a <class t> of 3 bytes.

Comment: that is actualy the case here , read the struct Foo declaration , and in that case what to do ?

Comment: i think tha address of the struct object need to be devisible by the sizeof the struct AND  each member of the struct need to be aligned ( it's relative address to the struct is divisible by it's size) and for an array of objects to be aligned the sizeof(struct) should be a multiple of sizeof(int)

Comment: Converting a pointer to `int` is wrong. Use `uintptr_t` for that. Then, the fact that the integer you obtain is basically the address so you can do modulo operations, is not guaranteed by the c standard. This is implementation dependent. This is why `alligned_alloc` was added to the C standard: there is no portable way to implement this.